# Find position of last match in R with regexpr

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics

I hope this question is appropriate.

IF I have a string like:

```
> x <- "ABCDDDDDABC"
```

If I use regexpr it returns me the position (and length) of the first match, while if I use gregexpr it returns position and length of all matches.

```
> regexpr("ABC",x)
[1] 1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 3
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
> gregexpr("ABC",x)
[[1]]
[1] 1 9
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 3 3
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

What I wanna do is only find the position of the last ABC, I don't care about any before it.
My desired output have to be:

```
[1] 9
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 3
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Which only return the position of the last ABC. Is there a simple way to do this, maybe the use of a wildcard I am unaware of? I have looked in the forum and online but I can not find a universal solution.

IMPORTANT NOTE: I do not want a regex that take into account the context around the ABC of this particular string. I want something that gives me the position of the last ABC of every string i may feed it with.

Comment: In base R:  `tail(gregexpr("ABC", x)[[1]], 1)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use the convenient function from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
as.vector(stri_locate_last_regex(x, "ABC")[,1])
#[1] 9
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. If I may ask another question.

Comment: @GabrieleGab  Are you saying that you have `c("ABC", "DCF")` etc?

Comment: @GabrieleGab  Perhaps `sapply(c('ABC', 'DAB'), function(pat) stri_locate_last_regex(x, pat))[1,]`